# Issue fortifying shapefile

Tags: r, ggplot2, gis, r-maptools, spatial-data-frame

I cannot fortify my areacode shapefile found [here](https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/item/4f4e4a19e4b07f02db605716).

I ran `install.packages("gpclib", type = "source")` as instructed in another Stackoverflow question and get the following:

```
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/gpclib_1.5-5.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 41980 bytes (40 KB)
downloaded 40 KB

'\\cdc.gov\private\M325\wol1'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
* installing *source* package 'gpclib' ...
** package 'gpclib' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs

*** arch - i386
gcc -m32 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/include" -DNDEBUG         -I"d:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local323/include"     -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99     -mtune=core2 -c Rgpc.c -o Rgpc.o
gcc -m32 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/include" -DNDEBUG         -I"d:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local323/include"     -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99     -mtune=core2 -c gpc.c -o gpc.o
gcc -m32 -shared -s -static-libgcc -o gpclib.dll tmp.def Rgpc.o gpc.o     -Ld:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local323/lib/i386     -Ld:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local323/lib -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/bin/i386     -lR
installing to C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.3/library/gpclib/libs/i386

*** arch - x64
gcc -m64 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/include" -DNDEBUG         -I"d:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local323/include"     -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99     -mtune=core2 -c Rgpc.c -o Rgpc.o
gcc -m64 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/include" -DNDEBUG         -I"d:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local323/include"     -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99     -mtune=core2 -c gpc.c -o gpc.o
gcc -m64 -shared -s -static-libgcc -o gpclib.dll tmp.def Rgpc.o gpc.o     -Ld:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local323/lib/x64     -Ld:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local323/lib -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/bin/x64     -lR
installing to C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.3/library/gpclib/libs/x64
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
*** arch - i386
*** arch - x64
* DONE (gpclib)

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\wol1\AppData\Local\Temp\1\RtmpInWyln\downloaded_packages’
```

I load the file by running the following lines

```
library("maptools")
library("ggplot2")
area <- readShapePoly("AreaCode.shp")
fort.area <- fortify(area, region = "NPA")`
```

When it attempts to fortify it throws the error:

> Error: isTRUE(gpclibPermitStatus()) is not TRUE

I suspect it has to do with the fact that I am on a government machine and my directories are not standard, but I really need a work around.

My ultimate goal is to create a choropleth map from the shapefile with data populated by a column of phone numbers. `NPA` in the shape file is the area code/region and I need to map the first three characters of the column below to that region.

```
Callers
7933959817
2575087989
3314687459
2734772497
5477907009
1129113780
6474925414
4681997266
9718681894
4875725216
```

sessionInfo()

```
R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United     States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United     States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] rgeos_0.3-19    ggplot2_2.1.0   maptools_0.8-39 sp_1.2-3       

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] colorspace_1.2-6 scales_0.4.0     plyr_1.8.4       tools_3.2.3          foreign_0.8-66   gtable_0.2.0    
 [7] Rcpp_0.12.6      grid_3.2.3       munsell_0.4.3    lattice_0.20-33
```

I think I've gone way in over my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [rgeos](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgeos/index.html) package instead of `gpclib`.

`gpclib` is deprecated in `maptools` and replaced by `rgeos`, due to licensing restrictions. By default, functionality in `maptools` that depended on `gpclib` has been updated to utilize `rgeos`.

```
R> install.packages("rgeos")
R> library("maptools")
Loading required package: sp
Checking rgeos availability: TRUE
R> library("ggplot2")
R> area = readShapePoly("AreaCode.shp")    
R> fort.area <- fortify(area, region = "NPA")
```

Comment: please edit your question and add the output of `sessionInfo()`.

Comment: I have added the session info.

Comment: Hmm, remove the `gpclib` package and try again, the code works on my computer with `rgeos`.

Comment: How frustratingly simple; it works perfectly now. I've marked you as the correct answer, thank you for your help!